# Calculate future inventory based an sales and production in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have 4 Tables: Storage, Sales, Prodcution, Production-cost

Storage example

| Day | ProductID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-27 | 1 | 900 |
| 2022-03-27 | 2 | 1200 |
| 2022-03-28 | 1 | 950 |
| 2022-03-28 | 2 | 1200 |

Sales example

| Date | ProductID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-2 | 1 | 50 |
| 2022-04-15 | 1 | 20 |

Production example

| Date | ProductID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-1 | 1 | 70 |
| 2022-04-20 | 1 | 10 |

Production-Cost example

| ProductID | 1 | 2 | glue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

---

Production cost describes if and how much of a certain product you need to produce something. In this example you need 1 product 2 and 1 glue to produce product1.

I want to calculate my future inventory based on the future sales and production in SQL. I had this working with some golang code, but would prefer if the SQL query did it alone.

I tried different joins but i could not figure out how to subtract the values correctly and form new rows.

Comment: Your tables dont have a column for quantity sold. There is no entry for the cost of glue. Please could you run the commande `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` for the 4 tables and and add the output to the question, as text. If you could write sample table lines for all tables for 2 products and the expected output, explaining how you got there I'm sure that we can find a solution.

Comment: i never asked about price calculation. This is not part of this question.
The coloum stating how much was sold is the "amount" coloumn in the table sales...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we get the most recent stock figures from storage, sum up the quantites produced and sold since (ignoring previous lines) and calculate the quantity in stock today.
I have included the table Production_cost in the join but have not used it. Should all product 2's be converted into 1's?

> ```
> create table Products(
> id int primary key);
> insert into Products values
> (1),
> (2);
> ```

> ```
> create table storage(
> Day   date,
> ProductID int ,
> Amount int,
> foreign key fk_storage_productID(ProductID) references Products(id));
> insert into storage values
> ('2022-03-27',    1,900),
> ('2022-03-27',    2,1200),
> ('2022-03-28',    1,950),
> ('2022-03-28',    2,1200);
> ```

> ```
> create table Sales (
> Day Date,
> ProductID int,
> Amount int,
> foreign key fk_sales_productID(ProductID) references Products(id));
> insert into Sales values
> ('2022-04-02',1,50),
> ('2022-04-15',1,20);
> ```

> ```
> create table Production(
> Day Date,
> ProductID int,
> Amount int,
> foreign key fk_production_productID(ProductID) references Products(id));
> insert into Production values
> ('2022-04-1', 1,70),
> ('2022-04-20',    1,10);
> ```

> ```
> create table Production_Cost(
> ProductID int,
> p1 int,
> p2 int,
> glue int,
> foreign key fk_production_cost_productID(ProductID) references Products(id));
> insert into Production_Cost values
> (1,   0,  1,  1),
> (2,   0,  0,  1);
> ```

> ```
> select
>   p.id as product,
>   st.Amount as latest_count,
>   coalesce(sum(sa.Amount),0) as sold,
>   coalesce(sum(pr.Amount),0) as produced,
>   st.Amount -
>   coalesce(sum(sa.Amount),0) + 
>   coalesce(sum(pr.Amount),0) as calculated_stock
> from Products p
> left join (
>   select ProductID, Day, amount, 
>   rank() over (partition by ProductID order by Day desc) rn
>   from storage )st on p.id = st.productID
> left join Sales sa on p.id = sa.productID
> left join Production pr on p.id = pr.productID
> left join Production_Cost pc on p.id = pc.productID
> where st.rn = 1
> and (sa.Day > st.Day or sa.Day is null or st.Day is null)
> and (pr.Day > st.Day or pr.Day is null or st.Day is null)
> group by 
>   p.id,
>   st.Amount
> ```
>
> ```
> product | latest_count | sold | produced | calculated_stock
> ------: | -----------: | ---: | -------: | ---------------:
>       1 |          950 |  140 |      160 |              970
>       2 |         1200 |    0 |        0 |             1200
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d06ea703a349e5f3e2dd435f01320fcb)*

Comment: Thanks alot, i take a look at it as soon as i can

Comment: i can use that and tweak it to fit perfectly thanks